# How to not ask the user for download prompt and set the download path programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, download, fileresult

I am developing an ASP MVC controller that returns a `FileResult`.

In the browser, I do not want to show the download prompt and download the file to a specific location on he client machine. Is it possible please?

Answer (score 3):

Afraid that's not possible, owing to  that would make it really easy to install a virus. What you could do is make an installer .exe that once run would put the files in the correct place, but that would add another step, which might be what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: But owing to applets it can be done, and we'll ask the user to trust our code. I want it to be done with .Net technology.